# Como fazer algo assíncrono com jQuery, busca no MySQL com PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Eu estou tendo muito problema com essa parte. Eu quero simplesmente fazer a uma busca no banco de dados e passar para o meu programa principal, isso sem dar um *refresh*. Eu sei fazer toda a parte do PHP e MySQL, entretanto a parte do jQuery já não é minha área, sei o básico de JS.

Seguinte: a pesquisa que quero é `SELECT questoes_resolvidas FROM dados_usuario WHERE id = id_usuario;`. Isso eu sei fazer. Mas o grande problema é pegar esse resultado e mandar para o meu *index.php*. Eu não quero mandar o resultado pra dentro de uma variável no *index.php*. Pode ser uma variável do próprio JavaScript mesmo.

Já tentei passar por `$_SESSION` mas não dá, pois tenho que atualizar a página para o `$_SESSION` pegar os valores atualizados. Eu não quero atualizar a página, mas a variável com a resposta do comando MySQL vai ser atualizada a todo momento que eu chamar a função `try_it()`.

Me ajudem, por favor. Já tentei aprender esse jQuery mas acredito que preciso aprofundar em JS primeiro, e não tenho tempo pra isso no instante.

Comment: Está usando algum framework?

Comment: somente o bootstrap mas uso muito pouco

Comment: No lado do servidor é PHP puro então?

Comment: sim, eu so quero retornar uma string da uma olhada nesse outro topico, é o mesmo problema e eu detalhei lá http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180156/como-buscar-valores-em-um-arquivo-php-com-jquery-ajax/180165#180165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito tempo (nem lembrava mais dessa pergunta) descobri com algumas buscas no Google. É bem simples:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",//Tipo da requisicao, pode ser GET, POST, etc...
    data: {dado1: "Dado 1",dado2: "Dado 2"},
    url: "url_do_arquivo_que_faz_as_coisas.php",
    beforeSend: function(){
        console.log("Isso executara antes da requisicao");
    }
    success: function(responses){
        console.log(responses);//Aqui são os dados vindos do PHP
    }
});
```

Se la no PHP tivessemos algo assim

```
echo $_GET['dado1'].' - '.$_GET['dado2'];
```

Teriamos o seguinte no nosso console apos fazer a requisicao AJAX:

```
Dado 1 -Dado 2
```

Espero ter ajudado quem precisa como eu precisava na época. Alem do mais, você deve colocar o código do JS em um função pq dai você chama quando quiser e quantas vezes quiser, o resto e só modificar...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma webservice para fornecer esses dados. Basicamente um arquivo que vai retornar apenas estes dados.

Primeiro crie um arquivo, ajax.php, por exemplo. Nele vc faz a consulta e escreve o resultado. Para facilitar para vc recomendo que imprima os dados parseados em JSON.

Dps disso, no jquery vc usa o método Ajax `$.ajax(options, callback)`

Assincronamente ele faz uma requisicao na URL q vc passar e quando terminado chama o callback. Quando cair no callback vc trata os dados que recebeu, ou uma eventual falha

Comment: Mano me desculpa mas a unica coisa que entendi é ajax.php, não tem como você me mostrar em codigo como fazer não?

Answer (score 0):

Tu vai ter que ter uma página para receber essa requisição ajax.

Exemplifiquei abaixo, a conexão com o banco é fictícia, só para ilustrar.

**ajax.php**

```php
// Apenas para exemplificar uma conexão com o DB
include("conexao_db.php");

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM minha_tabela
    WHERE minha_condicao = 1;
SQL;

$resultado = $db->query($sql);
$dados = $resultado->fetchAll();
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

// Parte importante
header("content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Aí no teu HTML tu vai fazer uma requisição AJAX para a página recém criada e inclui na página atual.

**index.html**

```html
<h3>Meus dados</h3>

<ul id="minha_lista"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Faz um requisição para a página "ajax.php", recebe os dados do servidor
    // e adiciona na lista vazia acima
    $.getJSON( "ajax.php", function( data ) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li name='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
        });

        $('#minha_lista').html(items.join(''));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Não quer funcionar, tá retornando NULL 5 vezes