# Como buscar valores em um arquivo PHP com jQuery - AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Pessoal quero buscar uma string em um arquivo PHP chamado busca.php eu quero retornar uma string para o meu index.php mas quero fazer isso quando chamar a função try_it(), tem alguma forma de fazer isso com o jQuery? Eu não quero que o index.php atualize a pagina, somente o valor da variavel que sera retornado pelo busca.php

**index.php**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="executar" onclick="buscar()" type="button">Buscar</button>

        <script>
            var stringDoPHPvemPraCa;

            function buscar(){
                //quero que a string do php seja setada em stringDoPHPvemPraCa no momento em que eu chamar essa funcao
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**busca.php**

```php
include 'config.php';
include 'database.php';
include 'connection.php';

$pesquisa = DBSearch("usuarios","WHERE id = 1","questoes_resolvidas"); // isso me retorna um array

// com as questões resolvidas onde "usuarios" é a tabela "WHERE id = 1" 
// é o parametro e "questoes_resolvidas" é o campo a ser retornado (a string em si)
$pesquisa[0]['questoes_resolvidas'] //isso que eu quero no index.php
```

Comment: Poste os códigos para podermos ajudar

Comment: ok vou fazer isso, só um momento

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesse tutorial](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-ajax-search/). A lista vc simplesmente carrega no foreach do seu banco, fazendo um like.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('url', {parametro: valor}, function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Acredito que o exemplo acima resolva.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Depois disso é só manipular da maneira que bem entender, por exemplo:

Levando em consideração que a sua url que retorna a busca seja http://localhost/busca.php, o seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim (obs: vc não tinha fechado a tag head no seu HTML):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="executar" onclick="buscar()" type="button">Buscar</button>

        <script>
            var stringDoPHPvemPraCa = '';
            function buscar(){
                $.get('http://localhost/buscar.php', function(data){
                    stringDoPHPvemPraCa = data;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Já o seu busca.php ficaria:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'config.php';
include 'database.php';
include 'connection.php';

$pesquisa = DBSearch("usuarios","WHERE id = 1","questoes_resolvidas"); // isso me retorna um array

// com as questões resolvidas onde "usuarios" é a tabela "WHERE id = 1" 
// é o parametro e "questoes_resolvidas" é o campo a ser retornado (a string em si)
$resultado = $pesquisa[0]['questoes_resolvidas'] //isso que eu quero no index.php

echo json_encode($resultado);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: como eu aplicaria isso no caso ali que postei o meu codigo?

Comment: primeiro, você deve dar um echo no final do seu php:  
`echo $pesquisa[0]['questoes_resolvidas']`  

Depois usar o `$.get` pra pegar o valor e passar para a variável:  

`$.get('caminho/do/arquivo.php', function(data){ 
    stringDoPHPvemPraCa = data;
});`  

Assim que você executar o método, ele colocará o valor na variável.

(ruim que comentário não pula linha).