# Submit ao digitar no input tipo texto para o codigo php na mesma pagina

Tags: php

Teria alguma forma de ao digitar o formulário vai enviando os dados para o código PHP sem ter de apertar o `submit`, simplesmente digitando na entrada de texto?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <label>nome: </label>
  <input type="text" name="Pesq" placeholder="Digite o nome"><br><br>
  <input name="EnviarPesq" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>

<?php

    $EnviarPesq = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'EnviarPesq', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if($EnviarPesq){
        $Pesq = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Pesq', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $itens_coletados = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '%$Pesq%'";
        $resultado_de_itens = mysqli_query($conexao, $itens_coletados);
        while($exibir_itens = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_de_itens)){
            echo "id:" . $exibir_itens['id'] . "<br>";
            echo "nome" . $exibir_itens['nome'] . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Tem, mas não da maneira que provavelmente você pretende. Leia sobre AJAX (inclusive aqui no site tem bastante conteúdo)

Comment: pode usar o evento `onchange` do input onde é digitado o nome e ir executando o código no `php` através de uma chamada `Ajax`

Comment: no caso seria algo parecido com isso então:      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(l) {
        }
    });

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180156/como-buscar-valores-em-um-arquivo-php-com-jquery-ajax), tem esse tutorial [aqui](https://www.gigasystems.com.br/artigo/35/pesquisa-dinamica-com-ajax-banco-de-dados-e-php) que pode ajudar também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar um evento `oninput` no campo e ir chamando o Ajax à medida que vai digitando no campo. Porém, eu sugeria incluir o Ajax numa função `setTimeout` com um pequeno intervalo (no meu exemplo eu coloquei *1000 milissegundos* = *1 segundo*), para que dê tempo do Ajax "respirar" antes de enviar uma nova requisição.

Incluí também duas linhas para abortar a última requisição do Ajax e apagar o `setTimeout` enquanto se está digitando de forma rápida:

```
if(AJAX) AJAX.abort();
clearTimeout(delay);
```

Isso é interessante porque cancela as requisições anteriores enquanto se digita no campo. Isso poupa o servidor de requisições excessivas, pois ao meu ver, o que importa é o resultado quando o usuário para de digitar por um breve intervalo.

Crie uma `div` após o formulário para receber os dados vindos do Ajax:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    ...
</form>

<div id="pesquisa"></div>
```

O script completo fica assim (veja no código as explicações):

```
var delay, AJAX; // declaro a variável do temporizador e do Ajax
$("[name='Pesq']").on("input", function(){ // captura digitação no campo

   if(AJAX) AJAX.abort(); // cancela o último Ajax, se existir;
   clearTimeout(delay); // apago o temporizador, para não criar um em cima do outro

   if($(this).val()){ // só chama o Ajax se o campo não estiver vazio
      delay = setTimeout(function(){ // redefino o temporizador
         console.log("enviando ajax...");
         AJAX = $.ajax({
            url: $("form").attr('action'),
            type: $("form").attr('method'),
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
               $("#pesquisa").html(data); // altero o conteúdo da div com o resultado
            }
         });
      }, 1000);
   }else{
       $("#pesquisa").empty(); // esvazia a div caso o campo esteja em branco
   }
});
```

### E o PHP?

Sugiro criar um PHP próprio para isso (digamos, `pesquisa.php`) e colocar apenas o código que faz a pesquisa e o retorno nesse arquivo (claro, incluindo também o código que faz a conexão com o banco de dados através da variável `$conexao`):

```
<?php

    // inclua aqui a conexão com o BD

        $Pesq = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Pesq', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $itens_coletados = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '%$Pesq%'";
        $resultado_de_itens = mysqli_query($conexao, $itens_coletados);
        while($exibir_itens = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_de_itens)){
            echo "id:" . $exibir_itens['id'] . "<br>";
            echo "nome" . $exibir_itens['nome'] . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
?>
```

> **Não esqueça de incluir a página no `action` dor formulário. Ex.: `action="pesquisa.php"`.**

Comment: Cara, ficou muito top esse código

Comment: Vlw! Mas fiz uma pequena alteração. Acho que não precisa daquela parte `var form = $("form");`

Comment: Tem mais uma coisa que faltou na parte do PHP, tem que tirar a variável `$EnviarPesq` e sua referencia e a condição no `if` que pega ela, porque não existe mais o botão, do contrario não funcionará.

Comment: Bem observado. Mas era só pra ter uma ideia mesmo. :D

Comment: Mas e se no caso eu depois que eu escrevesse e resolvesse pagar tudo no input, como faria para zerar o'que foi escrito na `div`?

Comment: pode fazer um `else` nesse `if($(this).val()){`, tipo: `}else{ $("#pesquisa").empty(); }`

Comment: Deu certo, eu já estava pensando em mexer na parte do `php` kkk, obrigado pela explicação!