# Como colocar um echo json_encode passando uma função PHP com parâmetro javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, json, autocompletar

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Eu tenho uma classe php que tem uma função que busca um array de dados e coloco um echo json_encode que vai entao fazer funcionar o autocomplete.
da seguinte forma:

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  $('#search').keyup(function()
 { 
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var a = $('#search').val();
      if (!searchField){
       return;
      }else
      {
       var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
       $.each(<?php echo json_encode($a->buscarArtistasBuscaPrincipal());?>, function(key, value)
       {
        if (value.nome.search(expression))
        {
           $('#result').append('....');
        }

       });
   } 
  });
 });
</script>
```

Funciona normalmente! Porem eu quero fazer diferente, eu quero buscar não todos os dados da tabela mas somente as palavras que correspondem com o que a pessoa digita, colocando por exemplo la na classe um select mais o menos assim:

`SELECT  nome_artista, img_artista FROM artista where nome_artista  like "."'%".$busca.`

No lugar dessa variavel $busca será passada o valor que está dentro da variavel javascript searchField, que é o que a pessoa digitou.
**Como eu faço para passar esse valor de searchField para variavel $busca?** 
Eu tentei fazer isso:

```js
$.each(<?php echo json_encode($a->buscarArtistasBuscaPrincipal("<script>document.write(searchField)</script>"));?>, function(key, value)
```

Mas não funciona, sei que PHP roda no servidor e javascript não, mas deve haver uma solução para isso.
Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito!

Comment: Seria interessante se você utilizasse o ajax pra realizar as requisições a cada alteração no input field. fazendo assim com toda vez que uma letra fosse digitada, fosse feito um select no banco.

Comment: É como o Vinícius disse acima. Da forma que está fazendo não tem como alterar o PHP porque ele já retornou os resultados.

Comment: E como eu faço isso?

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso, e semelhante a como vc vai resolver seu problema. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180131/como-fazer-algo-ass%C3%ADncrono-com-jquery-busca-no-mysql-com-php/333305#333305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Bom acredito que a melhor forma de fazer o que pretende fazer é, criando uma API em PHP que vai exibir na tela apenas o JSON de informações obtidas do banco de dados, criando essa API você poderá definir parâmetros GET de url, como por exemplo um limite de quantos itens vai buscar no banco, sendo assim depois de ter feito a API que joga apenas JSON na tela, você vai na sua pagina onde quer exibir as informações e usa o AJAX do Jquery para acessar a sua API e obter o JSON, e como você definiu parâmetros GET em sua API como o limite você vai poder passar no seu AJAX quando for obter as informações o quanto de limite quer que seja.

Acredito que essa seja a melhor forma.
Caso queira posso mostrar alguns exemplos, mas são grandes, tente fazer primeiro!